# Dúvida vetor de objetos

Tags: java

estou com uma dúvida de como prosseguir, há erros de sintaxe como vocês podem ver. Mas meus conhecimentos são básicos e estou tentando melhorar.
Tenho o seguinte programa. 
Um cadastro de Vôos, somente com número, origem, destino e numero de vagas.

Criei uma Classe

```
 package aeroporto;


public class aviao {
    aviao[] voo = new voo[i];

     int numero;
     String origem;
     String destino;
     int vagas;


 for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
void Cadastrar(int numero,String origem,String destino, int vagas)
{
    voo[i].numero = numero;
    voo[i].origem = origem;
    voo[i].destino = destino;
    voo[i].vagas = vagas;

}
}
```

e o programa principal é esse

```
package aeroporto;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Aeroporto {

public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

  int numero,vagas,i=0;

  String origem,destino;


  int op;
  do{
      System.out.println("****Menu Aeroporto****");
      System.out.println("1. Cadastro de vôo");
      System.out.println("2. Consultar vôo");
      System.out.println("3. Reservar Passagem");
      System.out.println("5. Sair");
      //ler entrada
     op =teclado.nextInt();
     if(op==4)
     {
         System.exit(1);
     }
     switch(op){ 
        case 1:

            for(i=0 ; i<5 ; i++){

                System.out.print ("Número do voo: ");
                numero =teclado.nextInt();
                System.out.print("Origem : ");
                origem = teclado.next();
                System.out.print("Destino : ");
                destino = teclado.next();
                System.out.print("Número de vagas : ");
                vagas = teclado.nextInt();

                aviao.Cadastrar (numero, origem, destino,vagas);
            }

            break;
        }      

   }while(true);
}

}
```

Peço para que as senhores e os senhores disponíveis, apontem os meus erros e como prosseguir. 
Obs:Estou tentando fazer esse vetor de objetos ao inves de usar o Arraylist, porque eu não tenho nem ideia de como faz.

Comment: Tem uma quantidade tão grande de erros que não sei nem por onde começar. Vou te dizer uma coisa que eu acho que é o melhor que posso te ajudar, mas a maioria que ouve isto ignora e continua batendo cabeça. Comece pelo começo, vai aprendendo uma coisa de cada vez, só passe para a próxima quando entender bem a atual. Vá aumentando a complexidade aos poucos, deixe OOP por último (este código não tem nada de OO). Enquanto não souber o motivo de cada caractere, até o espaço que tem no seu código não pode pensar em coisas mais sofisticadas. Eu comecei melhorar, mas ele tem erros conceituais graves,

Comment: então deixei pra lá. Não tem mais erros de sintaxe, mas ainda está muito errado:  http://tpcg.io/X9TuHo

Comment: @Maniero a forma que eu fiz, foi como eu aprendi na faculdade. Mas bom saber que há erros conceituais. Vou procurar aprender mais. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Para utilizar um arraylist, faça assim.

Collection colecao = new ArrayList();

apos isso você tem criado o seu ArrayList. Para adicionar itens simplesmente coleque o nome da sua coleção .add e dentro de () o objeto a ser adicionado.
exemplo: colecao.add(objeto1);

Como o ArrayList poderia te ajudar no seu problema. Então, primeiro aconselho você criar uma classe beans1, nela adiciona suas variaveis, assim.

```
public class Beans1 {
    int numero,vagas;
    String origem,destino;
    Collection colecao = new ArrayList();
}
```

e em cima das variaveis clique com o botão direito do mouse na tela do NetBeans e selecione a opção "Inserir Código", selecione a opção Getter e Setter, marque todas as opções e pronto.

Dentro destra primeira classe onde estará o seus Get's e Set's crie um método void para retorna os valores.

Agora na sua classe principal crie um Array que retorno os objetos da classe Beans1.

```
    ArrayList <Beans1> obj = new ArrayList<Beans1>();
    Beans1 o = new Beans1();

    o.getNumero();
    o.getVagas();
    o.getOrigem();
    o.getDestino();
    obj.add(o);
```

Comment: `Collection colecao = new ArrayList();`?? Acho que isso ta errado hein, nao seria `List<tipo> colecao = new ArrayList();`??

Comment: Sim, poderem o tipo Collection "nome da coleção" = new ArrayList(); ela serve para coleção do tipo object, e List<Integer> colecao= new ArrayList<Integer>(); só serveria para um tipo de list, como no caso lista do tipo objetos inteiros.

Como na questão acima ele diz precisar de uma coleção com vários tipos diferentes, citei esse.